# phonegap sqlite plugin to open big sqlite file?

Tags: sqlite, limit, cordova

i want to developer an app with phonegap. But in my app, i have to open some local sqlite files, which are larger then (5mb), (my files are about 20mb). Because of the size limitation of HTML5 database, i was suggested to write a plugin for phonegap providing database access. I just think someone should have the same problem like mine and have solved it with some plugin or workaround. Can anyone point me to some sources or blogs that are relevant to my problem.

Thanks

Comment: what platform are you on? What are you trying to save in the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check out my recent blog posting at:

> http://mattsnerdwerd.blogspot.com/2011/08/into-blender-javascript-sqlite-ios-and.html

In this posting I deal with this precise issue. Ultimately, this plugin already exists and credit must be given to Davide for posting his PhoneGap plugin at:

> https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin

Answer (score 0):

The Google Gears plugin (while 'deprecated') is supposed to be able to address this issue. If nothing else you could look at it for ideas on how to address the issue. It is expected to be supported into the future since it is deployed on a lot of sites and already in many browsers so that may also be an alternative for you.